# Hierarchical MAX

Tags: sql, mysql, max, mysql-logic

Is there a way to get a row that has the MAX() when two fields are considered, giving one of them precedence.  For example

```
ID     Column_A     Column_B
----------------------------
1        1              3
2        3              2
3        2              2
4        3              1
```

Would return

```
ID     Column_A     Column_B
----------------------------
2        3              2
```

Because both ID's 2 and 4 are MAX on Column_A, but #2 "wins" on Column_B.

What I'd like this query to do, in pseudocode:

```
If (It's the MAX on A, tied with nothing)
  Return it
Else If (It's tied for MAX on A and it's MAX [or tied] on B)
  Return it
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try...

```
SELECT *
    FROM mytable
    ORDER BY Column_A DESC, Column_B DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```

(if I understand the question correctly).

Edited as Matthew Purdon kindly suggested.

Comment: Is there a condition I could put in a WHERE or HAVING clause?  Because I'm using this inside another query which requires multiple rows.

Comment: You could put a `WHERE` clause after the `FROM` and before the `ORDER BY`. If you are using this in another query you may wish to remove the `LIMIT` clause. You can't use `HAVING` without a `GROUP BY` clause, and I don't see one of those appearing anywhere in the description of the problem.

Comment: Since it's the MAX that he wants, it should be:
ORDER BY Column_A DESC, Column_B DESC